# how to filter log messages in Azure for CLI command az monitor activity-log list

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-log-analytics

I can use this command  (Azure CLI)

"az monitor activity-log list ......"

to get all relevant events but I get million of them but I just need start, deallocate, stop - such events and there is a filter option but there are no manual pages or examples how to use it. Anyone who has used it, can throw more light on this, please?
(I tried various several methods like creating  alerts and pipes to put selected events into log analytics, event hubs, and storage but none worked :-( )

Comment: The command essentially calls the resr api - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/activitylogs/list, all the supported syntax [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/activitylogs/list#uri-parameters), if you want others, you need to use `--query` parameter to filter them https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/query-azure-cli#filter-arrays

Answer (score 0):

Just to help someone, posting my answer.

I used following commands for one of my tasks to filter logs:

```
az monitor activity-log list --subscription "subscription1" --start-time "2021-04-25
" --max-events "1000000" --query "[].{Caller_name:caller, EventTimestamp:eventTimestamp,resourceProviderName:resourceProviderName.value, ResourceGroup_Name:resourceGroupName, resourceId:resourceId, SubscriptionId:subscriptionId}"
```

Ref:
[az monitor activity-log list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor/activity-log?view=azure-cli-latest#az_monitor_activity_log_list)